# How can I solve this problem $\sqrt{30 \sqrt{30 \sqrt{30 ...}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

> How can I solve this problem $\underbrace{\sqrt{30 \sqrt{30 \sqrt{30 ...}}}}_{10 \text{ times}}$

Should I calculate it straight forward way adding the indices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$=30^{1/2+1/4+\cdots+\text{ up to ten terms}}$$

Observe that the exponent is in Geometric Series

Comment: Thanks. The answer is$30^{\frac{1023}{1024}}$. I was picturing it from innermost terms which lead to complication; $\sqrt{30*30^{0.5}}$